# Properly equally spreading list vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've searched for the issue, found some similar answers but not exactly what I am looking for, so here goes.

I've got an unordered list that needs to be spread equally vertically.
This is what I have:

```
<div class="icons">
<ul>
    <li><div class="twitter-icon"><img src="images/twitter.png"></div></li>
    <li><div class="github-icon"><img src="images/github.png"></div></li>
    <li><div class="linkedin-icon"><img src="images/linkedin.png"></div></li>
</ul>
</div>

.icons {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:5%;
    height:100vh;
}
.icons ul {
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.icons li {
    display: table-row;
}
```

This is the result:
[image: Currently happening]

And this is what I am looking for:
[image: Goal]

I hope this is enough info to explain my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `table` you can use a `flexbox` *display* like this:

```
display: flex; /* define a flexbox */
flex-direction: column; /* place it vertically*/
justify-content: space-around; /* spread it vertically */
```

See demo below:

```css
.icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.icons ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icons li {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="twitter-icon"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="github-icon"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="linkedin-icon"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not accomplish what he is asking. His problem is not with the icon spacing themselves or with the table layout. It's that he is setting `top: 0;` on the list instead of giving it some space to breathe.

Comment: the solution is correct - see what the OP says: "*I've got an unordered list that needs to be spread equally vertically.*" .... please re-read the question and kindly remove the down-vote